# How to add overlay to absolute positioned element?

Tags: html, css

Trying to add overlay to absolute positioned image. Below code is working but not perfectly.

Already tried to play with z-index property as well but no luck.

Below is the working example of below code on Codepen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRdmaX

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-80-80-6.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>                                  
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 97px;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.test img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6%;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    max-width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.test img:hover + i {
    opacity: .7;
    top: 7px;
}
.test i {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -50%;
    left: 3px;
    line-height: 68px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    transition: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.test h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply adding `pointer-events: none` to your `.test i` rule it will behave (not flicker on hover)

To make it match the `img`'s position/size, use the same position/size values

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 97px;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.test img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6%;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.test img:hover + i {
    opacity: .7;
    top: 6%;
}
.test i {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 6%;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;  
    line-height: 68px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.test h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-80-80-6.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>                                  
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

---

Added a 2:nd sample based on a comment

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 97px;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.test a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6%;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.test a:hover + i {
    opacity: .7;
    top: 6%;
}
.test i {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 6%;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;  
    line-height: 68px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.test h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-80-80-6.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive"></a>
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>                                  
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious. What would be the solution if image would be in <a> tag like below?


`<a href="#0" <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-80-80-6.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive"></a>`

Comment: @icookcode My I ask why you removed the accept? ... it still, before the added comment and 2:nd sample, answered your original question perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd sample. You da man.
Weird. I didn't change anything except just deleted my messy comment that I accidentally submitted earlier and reloaded the link.

Just marked it accepted again.